# Passing params into requests.Session.get raises TypeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am trying to understand why passing `params` into `session.get` raises TypeError in my example.
`response_get` returns a `200` response, while `response_open` raises TypeError.

```
import requests


class Foo:

    def __init__(self):
        self.session = requests.Session()

    def get(self, url, params=None):
        """Return a Response object."""
        return requests.get(url, params)

    def open(self, url, params=None):
        """Return a Response object using the Session object."""
        return self.session.get(url, params)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo = Foo()
    response_get = foo.get('https://estilen.github.io')
    response_open = foo.open('https://estilen.github.io')
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/estilen/Dropbox/Python/leapy/foo.py", line 21, in <module>
    response_open = foo.open('https://estilen.github.io')
  File "/home/estilen/Dropbox/Python/leapy/foo.py", line 15, in open
    return self.session.get(url, params)
TypeError: get() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Comment: Take out the params argument from the `self.session.get` and it works...

Comment: @whackamadoodle3000 That defeats the purpose of my question. :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The thing is that `get` takes [only one un-named (positional) argument](https://github.com/requests/requests/blob/master/requests/sessions.py#L512-L521):

```
def get(self, url, **kwargs):
    # ...
```

You are providing two: `url` and `params`.

To fix this, you need to provide `params` as a named (keyword) argument:

```
return self.session.get(url, params=params)
```

Comment: Interesting, I always assumed that `session.get` and `requests.get` are identical.

Comment: @LukaszSalitra Well, they behave the same way, but for some reasons have different signatures...